# RxCpp on Arduino?

Tags: c++

I would like to make use of some sort of event bus on Arduino.
Lately I have been making use [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp) on a number of different platforms, Android, Angular, iOS, etc, and found them very useful.

I tried to install the library and compile something (just including the headers in the example) and I got the following error.

```
/home/john/Arduino/libraries/rxcpp/rx-trace.hpp:97:57: error: 'exception_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
     inline void on_error_enter(const Subscriber&, const std::exception_ptr&) {}
                                                     ^
```

Before I spend too much time trying to force something that will not work, does anyone know if this will work on Arduino, or of any other event bus library that works well on the platform?

Comment: Well, exceptions are disabled, basicaly all c++ libraries aren't available and so on....